# How do I set Chrome download directory with Selenium & VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

Using Win7, Office2010, Chrome 58, and Selenium 2.0.9, I'm automating the downloading of a number of files from a few websites (NB, I actually need the files and the sites are not mine - I'm *not* testing my own site), and I'd like to control where the files end up being downloaded.

I have looked at quite a number of search results and everything I've found has led me to the following versions of code, each `Driver.SetPreference` variation has been tested independently and none of them work.

```
Private Sub DownloadDirTest()

  Dim Driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver
  Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

  Driver.SetPreference "browser.download.dir", "\\server\share\my\long\path"
  Driver.SetPreference "browser.download.dir", "\\\\server\\share\\my\\long\path"
  'after mapping Y: to "\\server\share\my\long\path" in Windows Explorer
  Driver.SetPreference "browser.default_directory", "Y:\"
  Driver.SetPreference "browser.download.dir", "c:\"
  Driver.SetPreference "browser.default_directory", "c:\"

  Driver.Start "Chrome", "http://google.com"

  Driver.Close

End Sub
```

As can been seen here:

[image]

Most of the references I've seen are for Python, Java or Ruby, and they all make reference to something like:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

There doesn't seem to be any equivalent `ChromeOptions` available to VBA.

**1)** Does anyone know the actual property name to correctly set the download directory?

**2)** I'm not particularly wedded to Chrome, though it seems to be faster than `IEDriver` (in my initial testing), and I can't get the current Firefox driver to work. If someone has pointers to how to reliably set the DL directory in either of the other browsers (and a link to an updated Firefox driver - I haven't been able to find it via half-hearted searching), I'm open to using those.

Comment: Be aware that addArgument, setPreference, setProxy and setProfile have to be called before the start command to be effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferences from your example are specific to Firefox. You need to set the ones specific to Chrome to change the download directory:

```
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "c:\temp"
driver.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
driver.SetPreference "safebrowsing.enabled", True
driver.SetPreference "plugins.plugins_disabled", Array("Chrome PDF Viewer")

driver.Get "http://google.com"


driver.Quit
```

Comment: Wow... talk about missing the forest for the trees... Are you the florentbr of [SeleniumBasic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) fame? If so, I'm honored! Also, is work continuing on the project - there doesn't seem to have been much activity of late.

Comment: The project is still alive. I will release a new version soon to comply with the new Selenium 3 API and to support the new driver for Firefox.

Comment: Spectacular! Very glad to hear it.